# Can I deduct my Goodwill donations from my taxes in Kentucky?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, donation, kentucky

On our Goodwill receipt, it says that special rules apply to donations **over $500**. We have made two donations this calendar year, each being in excess of $400 (i.e. total >$800).

Do the special rules for donations in excess of $500 apply to each individual donation, or to the total for the year?

Comment: Not to get hyper-technical, but you would be deducting it from your income, not your taxes. That is, it is a deduction not a credit.

Comment: @JohnFx - and upon reading the title, I had the exact same thought. And I'll think it until every last reader always understands the difference between deductions and credits....

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - it's vacation week :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [IRS publication 561](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p561/ar02.html#d0e1485):

> **Deduction over $500 for certain clothing or household items**.   You must
>   include with your return a qualified appraisal of any single item of
>   clothing or any household item that is not in good used condition or
>   better, that you donated after August 17, 2006, and for which you
>   deduct more than $500. See Household Goods and Used Clothing, earlier.

Based on this quote, it is per item, not per total. However, if you donate more than $5K, an appraisal report is needed.

In any case you need to keep all the receipts, and be able to substantiate your donation. I suggest keeping photographs of the donated items, and write down the prices in the thrift shop at which you're donating, as the donation value.

---

**Edit**

I understand from your comment that you asked about the Kentucky *State* taxes. Similarly to Federal, you fill everything on Schedule A of your State tax form. From my brief reading, they're following the Federal rules, and require form 8283 for non-cash donations over $500. You only fill the form once, if total donations is over $500, but on the form you write down items over $500/$5000 separately with additional supporting documents (appraisals etc) if needed, or nothing - if not needed (for items below $500).

Comment: http://www.goodwill.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Donation_Valuation_Guide.pdf

Comment: that's the IRS regs - this question is about KY (though that got edited out of the title)

Comment: You mean state taxes? Those follow the Federal rules (they require attachment of Federal form 8283 which is discussed in the publication I linked to).